# Swift 1.2 BAD_EXEC_ACCESS on startup

Tags: macos, swift

I have a simple app in Swift/SpriteKit/MacOS that I'm using to learn Swift. It mostly processes text files - which I'm happy to say, Swift is pretty great at.

I downloaded 1.2 and ran the converter and it suggested one line of code to be changed:

```
NSApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV)
```

Had to become:

```
NSApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv)
```

Now when I run the app it crashes with a BAD_EXEC_ACCESS on that line. The stack doesn't seem to show anything interesting; it appears to be crashing very early.

I put a breakpoint on the line and POed the inputs:

```
["/Development/PAIS/DerivedData/PAIS/Build/Products/Debug/PAIS.app/Contents/MacOS/PAIS", "-NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode", "YES"]
```

Nothing out of the ordinary there it seems.

Comment: Ok so I managed to trap early and this is some sort of memory problem, it's dying while trying to do an objc_release. Is there something like NSZombies to track this down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I hope this saves someone else some time. The problem is `fullName.componentsSeparatedByString`, which has a bug in it that releases the string on the Obj-C side and causes a double-release at the next GC loop. Use `split(striped!, { $0 == " "}, maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false)` instead, although that is much slower apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that every now and then Xcode tends to throw a hissy fit because of data that it's cacheing. Try closing Xcode, deleting the "DerivedData" folder and re-opening Xcode again. It will then re-index everything and hopefully this will sort your issue.

Comment: I see where you're going with this... but sadly no luck :-(